# adding dynamic content within body of an email (database mail) with sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

Is there a way I can add the time in the following query as the body of my email :

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'TEST_DEV',
    @recipients = 'xxx@gmail.com',
    @query = ' select 
            Percentage = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),100 - (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT case when PD.Exception  != ' ' then PD.Id  END) as float)/CAST(COUNT(PD.Id) as float)*100))
         from 
                DataBaseName.dbo.Product P INNER JOIN DataBaseName.dbo.LogProduct PD 
                ON P.LogId = PD.LogId

                WHERE   
                ResponseTime < GETDATE() and  RequestTime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -150, GETDATE())
                ' ,
    @subject = 'Test',
@body = 'Please check the attached file for Providers with Many unsuccessful calls between the time xx an yy',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

In the current line

```
@body = 'Please check the attached file for info on calls between the time xx an yy',
```

I would like to add GetDate() in place of xx and DATEADD(MINUTE, -150, GETDATE()) in place of yy ?

is it possible ?

```
declare @body nvarchar(max) 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'DEV',
    @recipients = 'xxx@gmail.com',
    @query = 'exec Database.dbo.spTest' ,
    @subject = 'Test',
 select @body = 'Please check the attached file for info on calls between the time ........................',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

Would you want me to do something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your @body variable before the EXEC statement and make it any string that you'd like.

**Edit**:

I updated this to be more verbose.  I dont have sp_send_dbmail configed anywhere to test, but I think it should work fine.  I created a string variable called @bodyMsg, set it to the string you want before the stored procedure call, then gave the value over to the @body variable in sp_send_dbmail.

```
declare @bodyMsg nvarchar(max) 

select @bodyMsg = 'Please check the attached file for info on calls between the time ' + convert(varchar,GETDATE()) + ' and ' + convert(varchar,DATEADD(mm, -150, getdate())) + '.'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'TEST_DEV',
    @recipients = 'xxx@gmail.com',
    @query = ' select 
            Percentage = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),100 - (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT case when PD.Exception  != ' ' then PD.Id  END) as float)/CAST(COUNT(PD.Id) as float)*100))
         from 
                DataBaseName.dbo.Product P INNER JOIN DataBaseName.dbo.LogProduct PD 
                ON P.LogId = PD.LogId

                WHERE   
                ResponseTime < GETDATE() and  RequestTime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -150, GETDATE())
                ' ,
    @subject = 'Test',
    @body = @bodyMsg,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

Then just pass the @body variable to the sp_send_dbmail stored procedure.  Different datetime formats can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: The type of `@body` argument should be `NVARCHAR(something)`. [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, corrected.  I was looking at that same page and didnt see the `n` before `varchar` O.o

Comment: Hey tommy_0 , I updated my answer above ? Is that what you meant  ? It doesnt work , but I am not sure if I correctly understood your point.What do you mean by pass the @body variable to the sp_send_dbmail. Can you look at my edited answer and let me know ?